# F# LiteDB [<BsonIgnore>] is Ignored?

Tags: f#, attributes, bson, litedb

Context: Running F# in a containerized environment

```
$ dotnet --version 2.2.203
$ uname -a
Linux SAFE 4.15.0-48-generic #51-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 3 08:28:49 UTC 2019 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

on Ubuntu 18.04 desktop machine.

This simple code ignores the `[<BsonIgnore>]` attribute. The value of `Ignore` is stored in LiteDB. Am I doing something wrong?
I've checked it by looking with the console command `$ dotnet LiteDB.Shell.dll micompany.db`:

```
...
> open micompany.db
> db.computers.find
[1]: {"_id":11,"Ignore":"ignore","Manufacturer":"Computers Inc.","Disks":[{"SizeGb":100},{"SizeGb":250},{"SizeGb":500}]}
```

This is the code:

```
open System
open LiteDB
open LiteDB.FSharp

[<StructuredFormatDisplay("{SizeGb}GB")>]
[<CLIMutable>]
type Disk = 
    { SizeGb : int }

[<StructuredFormatDisplay("Computer #{Id}: {Manufacturer}/{Disks}")>]
[<CLIMutable>]
type Computer =
    { Id: int
      [<BsonIgnore>] Ignore : string
      Manufacturer: string
      Disks: Disk list }

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =

    let myPc =
        { Id = 0
          Ignore = "ignore"
          Manufacturer = "Computers Inc."
          Disks =
            [ { SizeGb = 100 }
              { SizeGb = 250 }
              { SizeGb = 500 } ] }

    let mapper = FSharpBsonMapper()
    use db = new LiteDatabase("micompany.db", mapper)
    let computers = db.GetCollection<Computer>("computers")

    // Insert & Print
    computers.Insert(myPc) |> ignore
    printfn "%A" myPc

    0 // return an integer exit code
```

On the other hand, the `[<StructuredFormatDisplay>]` attribute of the `Disk` record is not correctly written (only a few dots appear in the console), when the `Computer` record is printed with `printfn "%A" myPc`. The output is:

```
Computer #12: Computers Inc./[...GB; ...GB; ...GB]
```

Is there anything else I need to say?